# Swisscom myCloud: obtaining the bearer token

Tags: api, curl, swisscomdev

When looking at the traffic while using Swisscom's myCloud web client, a bearer token is used for all interaction between the client and the server (`storage.prod.mdl.swisscom.ch`):

```
Authorization: Bearer 5E9Ra2n2kwI7JZDoy1f7og==
```

(this token is fake, obviously).

How can I obtain such a bearer token, using my Swisscom Passeport login and password? An example using `curl` is preferred.

Also, is there any documentation available regarding myCloud's API?

Comment: You could take a look at the following project: https://github.com/ThomasGassmann/swisscom-my-cloud-backup
Bearer tokens are obtained automatically as well (see `mycloud/mycloudapi/auth/bearer_token.py`)

Comment: @ThomasGassmann I've already stumbled upon your project, using Selenium or a similar software currently seems to be the only way to automatically fetch a token, unfortunately (just as I do it too). I can't understand why Swisscom won't use standardized OAuth in order for developers to obtain a bearer token.

Answer (score 5):

You have to follow the OAuth authentication flow from the Swisscom Passeport. Since Swisscom Passeport does not have an open API (as far as I know), you could make a PhantomJS script to enter the username and password and submit the login. Once the login is made, you should follow the HTTP redirects and get the access token.

I know you didn't want hear such answer, but, at the moment, I think there's no curl-friendly manner to login to myCloud.

EDIT:
Just to provide you the most complete answer: at the moment myCloud does not have any public API documentation. However, there are on-going discussions to open the API.